Update function in my CRUD with Repository-Services-Controllers architecture
I have a repository layer, service layer and controller layer for my user entity. I want to update one of my records by username.
This is my repository layer for the update:
public async Task<entities.User> UpdateUserAsync(entities.User entity)
{
    _dbContext.Users.Update(entity);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    return entity;
}

public async Task<entities.User> GetUserAsync(string userName)
{
    var result = await _dbContext.Users
                                 .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserName == userName);
    return result;
}

Now I use my update method in service layer:
public async Task UpdateUserAsync(UserUpdateRequestDto dto)
{
    var user = await _userRepository.GetUserAsync(dto.UserName);

    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("User not found.");
    }
 
    user.Email = dto.Email ?? user.Email;
    user.Name = dto.Name ?? user.Name;
    user.Family = dto.Family ?? user.Family;
    user.Password = dto.Password ?? user.Password;
    user.ConfirmPassword = dto.ConfirmPassword ?? user.ConfirmPassword;
    user.RoleId = dto.RoleId != 0 ? dto.RoleId : user.RoleId;

    await _userRepository.UpdateUserAsync(user);
}

This is my controller section for this function:
[HttpPut]
[Route("update-user")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateUserAsync(UserUpdateRequestDto dto)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);  
    }

    try
    {
        await _userService.UpdateUserAsync(dto);
            
        return Ok("User updated successfully.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}  

My problem is when I tried my update function with Swagger, it updates my record, but it shows string value for all fields, and If I enter username and a value for other fields, it updates but change the other records to string in database.
How can I fix this problem?

What values are changed to string? Why do you think so? Some of them are certainly a string, and so i don't understand clearly the question.

Swagger UI will use default values to indicate where you WOULD enter a value, and so it is likely sending those as the literal word "string". For a quick fix, you should remove those default values where it says string in the query body before you send the request. As an added security measure, you could also ignore values that you don't consider valid input. Something like this so that empty strings or null values aren't overriding your columns:
user.Email = !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(dto.Email) ? dto.Email : user.Email;

To illustrate further in swagger, if the request body it shows looks something like this:
{
  "name": "string",  // <-- you need to remove the word string here so you aren't sending a value
  "email": "string",
  // etc..
}

